# How can I sort a drop down list?

Tags: asp.net

I have a drop down list being populated from a database with

```
    <td >Start Week Ending Date:</td>
         <td class="data"><select data-bind="options: weekEndingDates, value: selectedStartWeekEndingDate, optionsText: 'Text'"></select></td>
```

In my database the dates are stored like 12-21-2014, 12-28-2014, 1-4-2015, 1-11-2015, etc. I would like them to be sorted as such (by year then month then day). However, when displayed in the dropdownlist that I explained above, they are sorted like a string. So when I have the month of October entered for 2014 AND 2015 it no longer displays them in order by year but instead shows them something like: 10-12-2014, 10-18-2015, 10-19-2014, 10-25-2015, etc.

Clearly this is very confusing especially since I removed the January dates for 2014, the drop down list starts with 2015 dates leading to many users thinking there are no 2014 dates available to select. Is there any way to choose how to sort this list so that it sorts by year first then month then day?

Comment: Looks like you're using knockout.js, but you've only selected `asp.net` as a tag. You should choose the tags that most precisely apply to your question.

Comment: you can sort in database using query

Comment: Post your query string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your platform, but one technique I've used is having two columns, one with the data and one with a sequential value used for sorting, and then hide the sequential column.  For example:
1 | A
2 | C
3 | B

And then hide the first column.  Just sorting the database query doesn't necessarily help if the listbox sorts itself.

If you can tell the list to not sort then use the database query.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a column in the database where you enter sort order numbers. 1,2,3,4,ect... Then you can order by that column in your query. Very easy to fix.